# How can I create private module without including private headers into the framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, private-header

I want to create a private module without including the private headers into the framework. I can compile the framework. But when I add it to the application project, Xcode gives the following error:

```
Umbrella header 'XXX_Private.h' not found
```

When I include the umbrella header into the framework, I get the following error (from inside the umbrella header):

```
XXX_Private.h: 'XXX/YYY.h' file not found
```

I tried to to set `Header Search Path` to the folder with the umbrella private header and all private headers, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple doesn't include private modules with their frameworks. Most likely, we shouldn't do that as well.